# Paper listing known Seiberg-dual pairs of ${\cal N}=1$ gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, research-level, supersymmetry, duality

Is there a nice list of known Seiberg-dual pairs somewhere? There are so many papers from the middle 1990s but I do not find comprehensive review. Could you suggest a reference?

Seiberg's original paper is [this Inspire entry](http://inspirehep.net/record/380062) and its cited by [these papers](http://inspirehep.net/search?p=refersto%3arecid:380062), but I do not know of any summary of the information in these 1000's of papers.

Answer (score 10):

A list of some dual pairs for exceptional gauge groups is in

- Jacques Distler, Andreas Karch, *N=1 Dualities for Exceptional Gauge Groups and Quantum Global Symmetries* ([arXiv:hep-th/9611088](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611088))

For non-exceptional gauge groups there are "lists" in the form of explicit algorithms for how to construct the dual partner, see section 4 of

- Subir Mukhopadhyay, Koushik Ray, *Seiberg duality as derived equivalence for some quiver gauge theories* ([arXiv:hep-th/0309191](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0309191)).

In as far as a comprehensive list of such lists is missing in the literature, one could construct one on a [page like this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Seiberg+duality) (if one had the time...)

Comment: For exceptional gauge groups, I would add the following papers to the one listed above. 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9702179v1
http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9712116v1

Comment: Thanks, [done](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Seiberg+duality#ExamplesForExceptionalGaugeGroups). Hm, that might need more discussion.

Comment: @Urs There are also Pouliot's class of Seiberg dualities, where a chiral theory is mapped to a non-chiral one: http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/9507018 etc. Can I convert my question to a community wiki, and make the answer itself as the list?

Comment: @Yuji: You can't award a bounty to yourself.  You can start an answer and flag it as community wiki.  Alternatively, you can edit an answer posted by another person. Any answer, after enough edits (don't know the threshold) turns into community wiki -- even if the original answerer doesn't want it to. So that's something to bear in mind for diplomacy. But if you don't want the bounty to be lost, you need to award it to someone who answers and is not you.

Comment: Nobody has given me the definitive list as the answer. So, the bounty will be lost, too bad!

Comment: @Urs: That paper by Mukhopadhyay and Ray only talks about SU groups, so your characterization of it as about "non-exceptional" sounds a bit off the point to me. Also, on your ncat page, you say Seiberg duality is formalized as derived equivalences of quivers, but mathematical quivers are again only for U or SU groups... I don't understand why most of the mathematicians only care about U(N) quivers. They can easily analyze SO or Sp quivers, can't they???

Comment: @Yuji: It is unfortunate that you haven't gotten a definitive answer, but if it doesn't already exist in the literature, it seems unlikely that you will find anyone here with the requisite background knowledge prepared to spend the time it takes to go through 1000 papers to generate the list.

Comment: @Joe I knew that the list doesn't exist in the literature, that's why I asked here :p  I learned that I should've asked this question after the tp.se community grew up more.

Comment: Maybe, but it really seems to require a huge time investment by anyone giving such an answer. Perhaps a better approach would be via community wiki, where people simply edit the top answer to add in any they are aware of that are not already listed.

Comment: I agree. I think Urs deserves many points anyway through his contribution to tp.se at large, so I "accept" his answer :)

Comment: @Yuji: for Urs to get the full bounty you have to explicitly award it. I am pretty sure just accepting an answer only awards half the bounty when the time expires. Perhaps that is your intention, but in case not, I figured I would let you know.

Answer (score 5):

I had seen some such "list" in the papers by Romelsberger and those by Spiridinov and Vartanov.
Maybe you are looking for papers like these,

- Christian Romelsberger, *Calculating the Superconformal Index and Seiberg Duality* ([arXiv:0707.3702](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3702))
- V.P. Spiridonov, G.S. Vartanov, *Supersymmetric dualities beyond the conformal window* ([arXiv:1003.6109](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.6109))

Comment: Thanks, but neither of them is complete, e.g. they don't contain duals with exceptional gauge groups ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a review by Chaichian, Chen and Montonen:

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007240

Comment: Thanks, but I was not asking for reviews. I'm looking for a comprehensive list of dual pairs.